# MLE of heteroscedastic model

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, least-squares, heteroscedasticity

I'm doing some practice questions for an upcoming exam and am unsure whether I've understood the problem correctly. Can anyone confirm what I've done or point out where I've gone wrong?

[image]

My final answer is the same as for the question below which is one that we did in a tutorial

[image]

Since we're still under the assumption of normal errors (albeit with different variances), the Least Squares Estimate should equal the MLE. Is that correct?